# How do I make animation start on touch and stop once touched again?

Tags: android, eclipse, touch

I have an Android app I made and everything works but I want to add a code that would stop the animation once I touch the screen again. As you can see in the code I got the animation to start but i can only stop it by exiting the program, I would like to be able to touch the screen a second time to stop the animation and the sound playback.

Thank You.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ImageView;



public class WigleActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

MediaPlayer mp;
AnimationDrawable animation;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sexy);

    ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageView1.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.wanim);
    animation = (AnimationDrawable) imageView1.getBackground();       
}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    mp.release();
    finish();
}

public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event) {
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    mp.start();
    animation.start();
    return true;

}
return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you onTouch code to the following:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event) {
  if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    if (animation.isRunning()) {
       mp.stop();
       animation.stop();
    } else {
       mp.start();
       animation.start();
    }
    return true;

  }
  return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much idk y i didnt see it before it so simple, im a beginner and i know a little python but never messed with java but its very similar as i am finding out.  Again Thanks

Comment: @RaulSanchez You should always check the documentation because in most of the case it contains what you want and it is where we find the answers. You can find it here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html