# how to check whether animated image is touched in ontouchevent

Tags: android, touch, android-animation

In my app, I used 6 image view and gave animation to all from bottom to top, width and height was fill_parent in linear layout, now I want to add touch event but I don't know how to check animated image is touched.
I tried following code but this not working.
What the method i should use and how is it possible?

```
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

 switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.imageView1:
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
          //  Intent intent = new Intent(YOUR_ACTIVITY.this, NEXT_ACTIVITY.class);
            //startActivity(intent);

        iv1.startAnimation(sci);
        sci.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   //iv3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
                iv1.clearAnimation();
                iv1.startAnimation(hyperspaceJump);
            }
        });
        }
    break;

    case R.id.imageView2:
    case R.id.imageView3:
    case R.id.imageView4:
    case R.id.imageView5:
    case R.id.imageView6:
    }
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674823/how-do-i-make-animation-start-on-touch-and-stop-once-touched-again and http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Touch_and_Multi-touch_Event_Handling

Comment: @Rachel Gallen. Actually problem is that touch event is working but not in animation image but in whole image view means i gave height full_parent so, touch event affect on whole image view form top to bottom. I want touch event work only on animated image. If i gave height wrap_content then touch event is only affect in bottom part but not on animated image. So, please tell me how to do this.. Sorry For My Bad English...Thank you...

Comment: i'm afraid i can'y be of any more help... :(